# avoiding duplicating file when editing with emacs

Tags: emacs

I always notice this file that duplicates the file I'm editing whenever I use Emacs:

[duplicated file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4VLB.png)

What code should I put in my `~/.emacs` file to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are backups, if you want to disable them add

```
(setq make-backup-files nil)
```

Alternatively, you can keep backups but store them all in a specific location by customizing `backup-directory-alist`, eg

```
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("" . "your/backup/directory")))
```